# How to convert C to assembly

Tags: c, assembly

So I don't understand assembly but i have some simple c functions i need to convert to assembly. Does anyone know how to convert these c functions into assembly?

```
void printChar( char ch )
{
    printf("%c",ch);
}

int checkRange( long value, long minRange, long maxRange )
{
    if(value >= minRange && value <= maxRange)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int isOdd( long value )
{
    if(value % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: well it will help me understand assembly language better for the homework if i understand how to convert these basic c functions into assembly

Comment: yes, but which cpu? There's SPARC, x86, etc. Which one are you dealing with?

Answer (score 11):

Put your functions in a `tst.c` file and use this command:

```
gcc -c tst.c -S -o -
```

Comment: Can you just code it from scratch. usually when you convert it like that it leads to excessive coding.

Comment: @AlexYang Usually when it comes to programming, you need to do excessive coding.

Comment: @AlexYang you need at least the basics, it's clear that you don't even know how to handle source code written in assembly, the assembly it's also strictly tied to the platform and the registries that you choose. Even if someone would like to write that for you, you are not saying for what architecture/platform you want it and what registry are you using.

Comment: @H2CO3 "Excessive coding" is something that I usually try to avoid. I usually prefer concise and efficient code over verbose and inefficient code.